# How can I allow SSH password authentication from only certain IP addresses?

Tags: ssh, configuration, security, password, authentication

I'd like to allow SSH password authentication from only a certain subnet. I see the option to disallow it globally in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
#PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Is there a way to apply this configuration to a select range of IP addresses?

Answer (score 196, accepted):

Use a `Match` block **at the end** of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
# Global settings
…
PasswordAuthentication no
…

# Settings that override the global settings for matching IP addresses only
Match address 192.0.2.0/24
    PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Then tell the sshd service to reload its configuration:

```
service ssh reload
```

Comment: I tried this (with 192.168.0.0/16 instead) and when I restarted the ssh service I got locked out. SSH refused any connections. Any idea why this could be?

Comment: @MichaelWaterfall It's impossible to tell with so little information. Make sure to keep a shell running until you've validated the new configuration. Restarting the ssh service doesn't affect active connections.

Comment: Hmm, okay I'll experiment and come back with more detail if I continue to have issues. Thanks!

Comment: The likely issue is that you put the Match block someplace in the middle of your sshd_config.  Match lines affect every following line until the next Match line, so they should be at the end of the file.

Comment: Despite the indentation in the answer, `sshd_config` is not Python `;)`

Comment: It works when that block is added at the end of file. But somehow, it generated an error when put just below "PasswordAuthentication no". journalctl -xe follows:/etc/ssh/sshd_config line 70: Directive 'PrintMotd' is not allowed within a Match block
Dec 19 09:08:31 inspiron systemd[1]: ssh.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a

Comment: @frepie The `Match` block extends until the next `Match` directive or until the end of the file. That's why you have to put it at the end.

Comment: Linux is simply amazing, thank you for sharing.

Comment: Or follow the Match directive with `Match All` to terminate it

Answer (score 9):

you can add:

```
AllowUsers user1@192.168.*.*, user2@192.168.*.*
```

this changes default behaviour, really deny all other users from all hosts.
Match block available on [OpenSsh version 5.1](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config) and above.

Comment: call I allow a group instead of a single user

Comment: @Lamar From `man sshd_config`, it looks like `AllowGroups` works the same as `AllowUsers`, but `AllowUsers` seems to take precedence over `AllowGroups`.