# How to allow a login/password from certain hosts and force a key-base authentication from others?

Tags: networking, ssh, login, password

When reading *[How do I restrict a specified SSH user to connect only from one IP or hostname?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/649796/how-do-i-restrict-a-specified-ssh-user-to-connect-only-from-one-ip-or-hostname)* I came close to solving a problem I have with specific logins - but it does not cover my case.

I need to ensure that an ssh connection to my host coming from anything else than `192.168.10.0/24` is authenticated via a key. Connections from `192.168.10.0/24` can use both (or only password based if this is a problem).

The [`ssh_config` man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/ssh_config.5.html) mentions in the PATTERNS section that

> the following entry (in `authorized_keys`) could be used:
>
> ```
> from="!*.dialup.example.com,*.example.com"
> ```

This would allow for a solution exactly opposite to mine: that some sources are **not** allowed to use keys but I do not see how to turn it into my need.

**How to force the use of ssh keys when the client does not connect from certain IPs?**

Answer (score 2):

According to the man page you can divide your `/etc/sshd_config` in sections that match hosts, the first section that matches being used:

So you could have:

```
# everything for your local hosts
Host 192.168.*.*
[...]
RSAAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication yes
[...]

# Everything for other hosts
Host * 
[...]
RSAAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no
[...]
```

To avoid all that duplication, there seems to be away to have blocks that are valid  for specific hosts:

```
Host * 
[...]
RSAAuthentication yes
[...]
Match 192.168.*.*
    PasswordAuthentication yes
Match all
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. The second block does not seem to be right, though: all clients would be required to use keys, and `192.168.*.*` would be denied passwords. I would have added a `!` in front of the match but this is a too small of an edit to be accepted.

Comment: Or just `PasswordAuthentication yes` instead of `no`, assuming that the default is `no` to account for the `Host *` earlier. I will test all that when back home (from vacation, as you are from the same region as I am :)).

Comment: Yes, Actually meant `PasswordAuthentication yes`. Answer corrected.